# Change password for logged in user (codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter, passwords

Is there any solution how to make change password for logged in user? i want to make  a change password for logged in user, the code i made only change user password with user id number 1. it doesn't change for logged in user. so any idea?

this is my controller:

```
    public function update(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Current Password', 'required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[20]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('newpass', 'New Password', 'required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[20]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[20]');

    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        $cur_password = $this->input->post('password');
        $new_password = $this->input->post('newpass');
        $conf_password = $this->input->post('confpassword');
        $this->load->model('queries');
        $userid = '1';
        $passwd = $this->queries->getCurrPassword($userid);
        if($passwd->password == $cur_password){
            if($new_password == $conf_password){
                if($this->queries->updatePassword($new_password, $userid)){
                    echo 'Password updated successfully';
                }
                else{
                    echo 'Failed to update password';
                }
            }
            else{
                echo 'New password & Confirm password is not matching';
            }
        }
        else{
            echo'Sorry! Current password is not matching';

    }
}
else{
    echo validation_errors();
}
```

This is my model:

```
 public function getCurrPassword($userid){
  $query = $this->db->where(['id'=>$userid])
                    ->get('users');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->row();
    } }

  public function updatePassword($new_password, $userid){
  $data = array(
      'password'=> $new_password
      );
      return $this->db->where('id', $userid)
                      ->update('users', $data); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize a session when the user logs in to the system at the beginning, and store the information of the user in that session, like this:

```
function login() {
    $query = $this->db->select(*)
                      ->from('table_name')
                      ->where('your parameters....');
    return $query->row();
}

function index() {
    $userid = $this->login()->id; //id of the user which is currently logged IN
    $this->session->set_userdata('current_userId', $userid);
}
```

You have now stored the id of currently logged IN user in the session. You can access the id by `$this->session->userdata('current_userId');`. Replace your `$userid = '1'` by the session data. Also, you will have to load the session library in order to do so.